# Visual Studio Team Services: delete repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Team Services, I mistakenly added a Git repository to an existing project which was under TFVC, so now the project has two repositories.

The problem is, I can't find any option to remove this repository from the project. The only option I find is to delete the entire project (obviously not what I want to do).

Searching online yields no useful results, as all the articles appear to be about deleting a project, can't find anything about removing a repository from a project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my case the solution from [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946400/visual-studio-online-delete-repository/38127061#comment57627930_34947098) by [Pascal Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/566901/pascal-berger) worked: I've created a second, empty repository, and after I had two repositories the "Delete" option become visible when right-clicking any repository.

Comment: I'll mark as correct "on faith", since I don't work on that project anymore ;)

Comment: I found it by going to https://<xxxxx>.visualstudio.com/_admin .  It lists all projects/repositories on the account? URL?

Click on the … for each project and the Delete option appears, as well as the rename option

Comment: @codeputer Sorry, I don't follow your comment. Are you asking a question or answering?

Answer (score 4):

Delete Git Repositories only available when you have multiple Git repos in one Git-based project. So there isn't any way to delete the Git repo in your case. You can submit a feature request on Microsoft User Voice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services

Comment: I think to clarify here, once you Git enable a team project by adding a Git repo, this is a one way change that cannot be undone (your team project will always have Git now). This means that you cannot delete the last remaining Git repo, only rename it.

Comment: Who had the brilliant idea to be able to delete a repo only when you have 2 repos?

Comment: @etragu.  Thank you for restoring my sanity!  Your comment was better than the answer.  Finally, someone who has the courage to state that something is obviously wrong instead of just accepting it as a fact of life.

Comment: Whoever came up with is anti-feature should give up and resort to growing turnips for a living. Taking away sharp tools from professionals because they might hurt themselves is beyond stupid!  If I want to delete a repo, then I should be able to. Yes, there's the chance of an accidental delete, but there's also something called a dialog box "Are you sure you want to hurt yourself?"  Alternatively, since you make it hard for your users to save you server space, you can also just archive it and allow them to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

In the Code hub on the top left there's a drop down to select between different repositories. At the bottom of this dropdown there's a 'Manage repositories' link.

In the version control administration you can right-click the repository and choose 'Delete repository'.

Direct link is:
`https://YourTenant.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/YourTeamProject/_admin/_versioncontrol`

Replace `YourTenant` and `YourTeamProject` with the appropriate values.

If you don't see the link in the dropdown or get an error message you most probably don't have enough permissions.

Comment: I am the only administrator and the only option I see is "Rename Repository", no option to delete at all!

Comment: I also tried setting all permissions to "allow" for all the members of the team, but none of them see the delete option either.

Comment: Can it be that the Git Repository is the default repository of the team project (which cannot be deleted)? If you temporarily create a new repository do you see the delete option on the new repository?

Comment: Mmm, I don't think so, the project was originally created with a Team Foundation Server repo, which you can't do anything about (not even rename). The git one was added later, and now cannote be deleted, only renamed.

Comment: Sorry, not really an idea in this case. Maybe some issue with projects with different repo types. I only worked with project types which only had Git repos.

Comment: If you browse to https://YourTenant.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_admin, you can select Delete from the drop down arrow next to each repo

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Team Project and the remaining repo will be deleted also. That way you're not left with an empty Team project