# How to remove Only ONE Git repository in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have the same issue than this post:

[How to remove Git repository in TFS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794126/how-to-remove-git-repository-in-tfs-2015)

But if I'm no mistaken there is no solution when we have only one GIT repo.
The only solution to delete the first GIT is to create a new one. So if i do that I will have two GIT, after that I could delete the first one (GIT REPO 1), but the second one will stay (GIT REPO 2) and cannot not be delete.
So the problem is still the same.

So my question is, Is it possible to delete all depository to have no GIT entry at all ?

Best Regards,

Comment: No. Just use RBAC to restrict access so no one can do anything with it and pretend it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove Only ONE Git repository in TFS?

I am afraid it is impossible to delete all depository to have no GIT entry at all.

According to the document [Delete a Git repo from your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/delete-existing-repo?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts):

[image]

And this document applies to `Azure DevOps Server 2020 | Azure DevOps Server 2019 | TFS 2018 | TFS 2017 | TFS 2015`

So, to delete the only Git repo in a Project, create a new Git repo first, then delete the repo.